# How to load the css according to browser?

Tags: html, css

I have designed a webpage for my project which looks fine in firefox and chrome when i look into internet explorer the image position and table position everything wasn't aligned properly.
Even i tried to import reset.css file(eric's recent version).This gives improper alignment tables of all the pages.

Is it good to load the css based on user agent?

```
   if ie:
      <link ....</link>
   else:
      <link>...</link>
```

How it is supposed to do?

Also, How to adjust the layout which should be adoptable across all resolution screen?

My page is looks fine when i do in 12-15 inch resolution screens.Some wider screens it doesn't look good.

How it is supposed to be handled it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The table issues can usually be fixed with display. What versions of ie are you going to support?

Comment: @pKs site is not opening ,you should remove the comma at the end

Comment: @prash http://sass-lang.com check it. Its like LESS library.

Comment: @saravanan: See my answer given below. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css"/>

<![endif]-->
```

[stylesheet for ie](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

you can adjust the layout using media queries,what ever the resolution you can choose

something like

```
@media all and (min-width:500px) { … }
@media (min-width:500px) { … }
```

[media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 2):

Your can use `conditional comment` for IE browsers. Write like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css"/>
Special instructions for IE 8 here
<![endif]-->
```

Read this for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

### By using [**CSS Conditional Comments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you may target your browsers.

*By Adding following lines in your `<HTML>` page you may define browser specific style-sheets or java-script files.*

**For IE Browsers**

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**For Non-IE Browsers**

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/non-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

### By using [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) you may create a responsive website's layout by targeting desired screen resolutions.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 320px) {
   div { background: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 700px) {
   div { background: green; width: 300px; height: 100px;  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1025px) {
   div { background: red; width: 600px; height: 100px;  }
}​
```

[**EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h8Nyg/1/show/)

You may learn in details that [**How to use Media Queries**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)